# Navigation drawer doesn't close

Tags: android, android-navigation

The navigation drawer in my app is not closing. I am using activities instead of fragments. When i click on any item in the `listview`, it opens other activities as it should but when i go back, the drawer is still open. I have tried using `DrawerLayout.closeDrawers();` but it did not work. How do I close the navigation drawer?
 
Here is my code:

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
final String[] data ={"Aluminium","Gold","Zinc"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){

            switch (pos){
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Aluminium.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Gold.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Zinc.class);
                    startActivity(i3);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show where and how you tried drawer.closeDrwaer()?

Answer (score 7):

have you tried :

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
```

You can add this before calling `startActivity()`

Comment: Don't know why but `closeDrawers` didn't work but `closeDrawer(Gravity...)` did, so thanks you gave me the clue I need, didn't know there were more methods

Answer (score 5):

In continuation to others answers and @ Chinmay Dabke question of 'but the drawer closes half then pauses and then closes fully' in one of the comments, here is what you could do:

first as others suggested,
this line is missing. `drawer.closeDrawer(navList);`

And as far as the pausing of drawer is concerned while closing, you could do something like this.
use a Runnable and a Handler like this:

```
mRunnable = = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         //say
         selectItem(pos); //Implement your switch case logic in this func
    }
}
```

and then in the `onDrawerClosed` overrided method

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

if (mRunnable != null) {
    mHandler.post(mRunnable);
    mRunnable = null;
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

I would suggest you to use fragments for navigation drawer and to solve this issue of drawer not closing properly, I found this article very useful (using fragments). http://www.michenux.net/android-asynctask-in-fragment-best-pratices-725.html

Comment: I put the  runnable initiation in the onclick event so it could get what it needed from the row.  Then as droidx did put the post in the onDrawerClosed.  Fixed the stutter nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Call

```
drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
```

in `onItemClick()` method

Answer (score 4):

Try

`drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);`

Your `drawer` gravity is `start` so Use that to close the corresponding `drawer`

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see any code where you are closing the ListView from drawer... close the ListView Drawer on ListItem click...

```
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
            switch (pos){
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Aluminium.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Gold.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Zinc.class);
                    startActivity(i3);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Gopal it works! but it closes half then pauses and then closes fully. What should i do?

Comment: @ChinmayDabke move `drawer.closeDrawer(navList)` statement after the switch statement I mean after starting Activity...

Comment: I wrote <drawer.closeDrawer(navList)> after <startActivity(i)> but it still pauses! Please help.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke intentionally drawer layout won't pause during closing... may be Application thread doing some work on UI like starting Activity which pauses Drawer for small amount of time...

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the drawer on list item click

```
drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
```

Also what is the use of `FrameLayout` in your xml. It is not used as a container to add or replace fragments

Comment: I am using the navigation drawer to switch between activities

Comment: @ChinmayDabke so what?

Comment: Nothing i just mentioned. No disrespect sir!

Comment: @ChinmayDabke i was asking what happens if you close the drawer?

Comment: When you close the drawer, the item you clicked open its respective activity.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke what happens if you use the above code to close the drawer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45642/discussion-between-chinmay-dabke-and-raghunandan)

Comment: let us continue this discussion in chat

Answer (score 2):

> call the drawer.closeDrawer(navList); function before switch case

Comment: Thanks Mohan! But it closes half then pauses and then closes fully. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(navList))  
  {  
      drawer.closeDrawer(navList);      
  }
```

In onResume() and start of onItemClick() method.

or you can try another approach..run a Ui thread when you are selecting drawer item

```
private void selectDrawerItemItem(final int position){

     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ItemClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     darwer.closeDrawer(navList);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment(Activity.this);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(Fragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
             fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            navList.setItemChecked(position, true);

            setTitle(" " + navListTitles[position]);
        }
    }, 200);


    // update the main content by replacing fragments


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.

I used

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
```

before starting my new activity. It beautifully slides the drawer back in.

Answer (score 1):

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

it works

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:
Lets say you have the drawer class

in your activity call the class as and make a vaiable and assign it(put the drawer layout within a fragment for smoother user experience)

```
Drawer drawer;
drawer = (Drawer)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.theid);
drawer.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
//End for right and Start for left
```

Hope it helps